# SharePoint 2010 - Cache JSON Response for global access

Tags: json, caching, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I currently have a site that is running slow due to a homepage that makes multiple Web Service Calls to obtain list data in a JSON response, and high number of users accessing that page at once.

We're looking at reducing the calls as much as possible, but we'd also like to know if it's possible to globally cache the response when the first person hits the site, and then pull from that cache until that data expires (say 24 hours later) as opposed to having each user call the service every time they access the site?

I'm operating in a role as a front-end developer, with support from farm administrators and system engineers. I'm currently just trying to do some research for possible solutions, and would really appreciate any direction. I've searched quite a bit and found some information about using AppFabric and distributed caching, as well as some other options, but I haven't found anything that definitively says its possible to write a JSON response to a global cache that all users can access.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Jonas

Comment: Your WebService calls is to Sharepoint REST services or you call your custom WebService ? Web Services calls (and response) are equals for all users ? For Sharepoint services one possible solution is to add another Sharepoint Front End or you can develop a proxy service with cache behind. Try to post more infos regarding WebServices.

Comment: We call a REST service. 

$.getJSON("/(Site)/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/(ListName)")

Answer (score 0):

You can write a simple Caml Query to get modified date column of list items order by desc and take a row limit of 1. This is the date of last modification of the list items.

Now you can save the last item modified date to:

1. [Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie)
2. [Local Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage)

You can implement the [Application Cache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Using_the_application_cache) for storing a copy of your json and refresh it when the last item modified date value change.